# Change color of stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to change the color of single bar of `stacked bar chart` in to two types.
Lets say, I have two option `APP Used` and `APP not used`. I want to have a green color for `APP used` and red color for `APP not used` option. The default was black and green so I do not want that. I tried to change color by adding following option  but it made the whole bar same color:

```
 colors: [
     '#4572A7',
     '#AA4643'],

 plotOptions: {
     column: {
         colorByPoint: true
     }
 },
```

However, I want to have the different color for each category.
Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rkahuja99/qqes1sw6/

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The example will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-placement/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `plotOptions` you don't need `colorByPoint` setting. It should be:

```
colors: ['#4572A7', '#AA4643'],
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'percent'
    }
},
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qqes1sw6/3/